# PMML // tree based embedding by modifying a random forest model file

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, embedding, pmml

Following this paper:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7712003/   I have a question on how to apply, e.g. XSLT, to modify a PMML file with random forest to do the following:-

- tree based embedding

  - label each tree leaf with an id
  - return the leaf id used for prediction
- "individualise" trees in the forest:  use for example multipleModelMethod="modelChain" to create individual output from each tree

so if I have a random forest with 2 trees each with 5 terminal leafs I would like to have the output

one hot encode "t.l" where t=tree id and l=leaf id
0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4  1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
1   0   0   0   0    0   1   0   0   0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> how to apply, e.g. XSLT, to modify a PMML file

Consider using a proper PMML library such as [JPMML-Model](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model) for this. It provides a special-purpose Visitor API for traversing and modifying PMML data structures.

> return the leaf id used for prediction

Append the following `OutputField` element to all `TreeModel/Output` elements:

```
<OutputField name="id(node)" feature="entityId" dataType="string" optype="categorical"/>
```

This uses the "entity identifier" mechanism to extract the identifier of the winning `Node` element.

There is no need to label nodes manually. If the `Node@id` attribute is missing, then implicit 1-based indices are returned.

> "individualise" trees in the forest

The trees in the random forest model can be identified by the `Segment@id` attribute.

For example, the following `OutputField` element will return the id of the winning node of the seventh decision tree:

```
<OutputField name="id(node, 7)" segmentId="7" feature="entityId" dataType="string" optype="categorical"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is valuable info!

This last bit is now missing:   how can I determine all the id of the terminal leafs put them all in the output.  I know it gives me a vast array of empty columns - but i need a one hot encode of all terminal leaves.

Comment: You don't need to one-hot-encode node identifiers at the PMML level. Simply configure your network model to accept categorical integer features - one feature per tree, and the valid value range of said features is known beforehand. For example, when using sciikit-learn random forests, then you get balanced binary trees, which have a very rigid tree structure. When you think about it, then the network should actually be able to figure out the "internal structure" of features all by itself during training.

Comment: This SO question should be re-phased as "How can I connect the output of a decision tree ensemble model to the input of a neural network model (using PMML language constructs)". One-hot-encoding is a too low-level solution. With PMML you're operating at a much higher level (eg. categorical features can be used as-is), and the solution is conceptually different/better.

Comment: Thanks again - I think the solution is found then : O )